# How to ind out potential program logic error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I was once asked a question:

*"If you were given a program with source code, the program goal is to get input from end users for their passwords. It filters out illegal input like number "8", and then stores the input.
The source code compiles and runs good for most common input. But it embeds logic errors like overlook some input errors. And might dump under special illegal input.
How you decide whether the program contains problem? If have, how to solve?"*

Could you think of a good way to test the program?
Is there any smart tools to test all possible inputs for my program? Or smart tools to verify the program?

I imagine a good way is "not modify the code" but "just run/test the code" to find potential problems.

PS:: suppose VS 2012 C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no right answer. The purpose of the question is to get you to reason out loud about a problem so the interviewer can see how you think.